# Rails 7 with turbo and JS event listeners

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, turbo-rails

I use Rails 7 and turbo. I want to use a Bootstrap 5 admin theme but having the following issue:

To bind the click event to the menu toggle button, there is some code like this:

```
let menuToggler = document.querySelectorAll('.layout-menu-toggle');
```

This works once but of course after a page change (with turbo) this dies not work anymore since the toggle button is loaded in the DOM and the binding does not work anymore.

I know that I can bind events to the parent (body) but I was wondering if there is another way to solve this. The entire admin theme is full of JS and I do not want to rewrite all the JS.

Does turbo have any solution for this kind of challenge?

Comment: No - there is no magic wand that you can wave over a bunch of [non-idempotent junk code](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent) to fix it instantly. The solution to the problem is to not use old garbage libraries and [use event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation). [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/) for example makes event delegation easy.

Comment: PS. Yes, that first link is for Turbolinks but it is explains the basic problem very well. This isn't really a new thing either - dealing with binding events and a dynamic DOM has been an issue as long as JS has existed.